# Accessing a hash from one model class to other in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class FileInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {:UNAPPROVED => 1, :APPROVED => 2, :PROCESSED => 3 }
  attr_accessible :id, :status
  validates :status, :inclusion => {:in => STATUS.values}    
end
```

I want to access `STATUS` hashmap in another class:

```
class FileInfoObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(file_info)        
    if file_info.status.eql? 2 //HERE, I want to access STATUS[:APPROVED]
       // Some logic    
    end
  end
end
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Try FileInfo::STATUS[@m.column_name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileInfo::STATUS` to access the hash itself, it's a class method so call it on the class.